# Can you extend HttpContext.Current.User.Identity properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Is there a way to override `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` to add another property (screen name)?

My application uses `Identity` and I've left the unique identity as email. I store user data such as first / last name in a separate `"Profile"` table. Is there a way to store this information somewhere within `HttpContext.Current`?

It doesn't necessarily need to be within `User`. I have had a search and noticed there's a `HttpContext.Current.ProfileBase`. Not sure how to use it though - and I really don't want all the excess stuff that base comes with.

Comment: As I understand you have different table with additional user data. And you want fetch current user's data. Am I right? Are you using Entity Framework? And way you prefer to store those data to another table?

Comment: `User` is really just an `IPrincipal` and `Identity` is just `IIdentity`. You can easily create your own implementation of `User` with it's own implementation of `Identity`. They just need to adhere to the interfaces.

Comment: Since you're using Asp.Net Identity, the way to do with is with Claims.  See my answer posted below.

Comment: Thanks, I am testing the answers tonight and will accept one then

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using Asp.Net Identity, then this is very easy to do with claims.

In your `SignInAsync` method (or, wherever you are creating the claims identity), add the `GivenName` and `Surname` claim types:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    // Add the users primary identity details to the set of claims.
    var your_profile = GetFromYourProfileTable();

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, your_profile == null ? string.Empty : your_profile.FirstName));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, your_profile == null ? string.Empty : your_profile.LastName));

    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

You then use an extension method to `IIdentity` to pull the information out of the claims identity:

```
public static ProfileName GetIdentityName(this IIdentity identity)
{
    if (identity == null)
        return null;

    var first = (identity as ClaimsIdentity).FirstOrNull(ClaimTypes.GivenName),
    var last = (identity as ClaimsIdentity).FirstOrNull(ClaimTypes.Surname)

    return string.Format("{0} {1}", first, last).Trim();
}

internal static string FirstOrNull(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string claimType)
{
    var val = identity.FindFirst(claimType);

    return val == null ? null : val.Value;
}
```

Then, in your application (in your controller or view), you can just do:

```
var name = User.Identity.GetIdentityName();
```

Comment: Is it possible to override the `Name` property?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers the `Name` property of what?  Can you give some more detail?

Comment: The `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. Also see [this question I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336360/override-httpcontext-current-user-identity-name/32341483#32341483).

Answer (score 6):

You can put value in HttpContext.Current.Items. 
It is dictionary which lifetime is single request.

You can use it like this:

```
public static string CurrentScreenName
{
    get
    {
        string screenName = (string)HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentScreenName"];

        if (string.NullOrEmpty(screenName))
        {
             screenName = ResolveScreenName();
             HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentScreenName"] = screenName;
        }
        return screenName;
    }
}
```

It will execute ResolveScreenName() only once for single request.

Also you can make extension method to access screen name from IIdentity

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetScreenName(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        return CurrentScreenName;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
string screenName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetScreenName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! You need to create your own type that implements from `IPrincipal`, and take over security yourself. You can authenticate the user in an OWIN step, manually setting `context.Request.User`.

Answer (score -1):

I found one implementation:

```
var profile = db.UserProfile.Where(u => u.UserId == user.Id).FirstOrDefault();
ProfileBase httpProfile = ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName);
httpProfile.SetPropertyValue("FullName", profile.FullName);
httpProfile.SetPropertyValue("FirstName", profile.FirstName);
httpProfile.SetPropertyValue("LastName", profile.LastName);
```

Then to get later...

```
ProfileBase userProfile = ProfileBase.Create(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
var fullName = userProfile.GetPropertyValue("FullName"));
```