# Override HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net, webforms, windows-authentication, claims, iidentity

I am trying to hook into the Web Forms ASP.NET pipeline and extend the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` in such a way that the `Name` property returns a custom implementation.

One possible approach which I have found [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974228/can-you-extend-httpcontext-current-user-identity-properties#31976327) that it is possible to add new properties by adding claims. The two questions I have are:

1. Where to add the claims in the ASP.NET Web Forms pipeline? And
2. Is it possible to override the existing `Name` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  implement the PostAuthenticate event in your application's Global.asax file. The PostAuthenticate event occurs after the FormsAuthenticationModule has verified the forms authentication cookie.

the following link might be helpful:  http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/860607-setting-httpcontext-current-user

Comment: Seems like we need a whole new provider if we want to use a name property. We will work around it by introducing another variable. Thanks for the idea about the `PostAuthenticate` event. Note that it does not fire for Windows authentication.