# Unable to add and fetch custom claims values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin, claims-based-identity

I am using mvc 5 with identity 2.0. I want use custom claim values over the application but I get null values. What am I doing wrong?

**Updated code**

**Login Code in account controller**

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password))
            {
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
                var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);


                //Generate verification token
                Dictionary<string, string> acceccToken = null;
                if (SignInStatus.Success == 0)
                {
                    var userDeatails = FindUser(model.UserName, model.Password).Result;
                    if (userDeatails != null)
                        acceccToken = GetTokenDictionary(model.UserName, model.Password, userDeatails.Id);
                }
                if (model.RememberMe)
                {
                    HttpCookie userid = new HttpCookie("rembemberTrue", "1");
                    userid.Expires.AddDays(1);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(userid);
                }
                else
                {

                    HttpCookie userid = new HttpCookie("rembemberTrue", "0");
                    userid.Expires.AddDays(1);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(userid);

                }
                #region custom claims


                var claims = new Claim[]
                           {
                    new Claim("urn:Custom:MasterUniqueId", Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()))
                                };
                ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
                authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
```

**Starup.Auth.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                },
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
            });
```

**another controller**

Here I am trying to fetch that claim values but it shows null

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
var res= identity.FindFirst("urn:Custom:MasterUniqueId");
```

> res is null

Comment: Can you show the full sign in code that you're using?  Is the method that this code in in properly async?  Also, are you missing a `app.UseCookieAuthentication(...)` in your startup?

Comment: @BrendanGreen, I have updated my question, Please have a look

Comment: Can you see what the output of `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and `User.Identity.Name` is?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846816/how-to-get-custom-property-value-of-the-applicationuser-in-the-asp-net-mvc-5-vie/38847016#38847016) is an example.

Comment: Approach is right , if you are getting User.Identity , you are on right Track , further then you can cast `User.Identity.Claims` to `ClaimsIdentity` and fetch requests keys.

Answer (score 1):

You should add those claims on identity validation phase. Please check similar implementation here: [Server side claims caching with Owin Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192428/server-side-claims-caching-with-owin-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

In your account controller, to get a valid authenticationManager, you should use  `Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication`. Im affraid `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication` gets you a fresh authenticationManager instead of the current Owin context one

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert identity to claims identity and then try to get claim using identity type

```
(HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "urn:Custom:MasterUniqueId")?.Value
```