# How to Get Custom Property Value of the ApplicationUser in the ASP.Net MVC 5 View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In the `ASP.Net MVC 5`, the `ApplicationUser` can be extended to have custom property. I have extended it such that it now has a new property called `DisplayName`:

```
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } //here it is!

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager) {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

I also have updated the database table using `Update-Database` command in the `Package-Manager Console` in `Visual Studio` to ensure the consistency between the `ApplicationUser` `class` and the `AspNetUsers` table. I have confirmed that the new column called `DisplayName` is now exist in the `AspNetUsers` table.

[image]

Now, I want to use that `DisplayName` instead of the default `UserName` for the text in the original `_LoginPartial.cshtml` `View`. But as you can see:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
</ul>
```

The original `_LoginPartialView.cshtml` is using `User.Identity.GetUserName()` to get the `UserName` of the `ApplicationUser`. The `User.Identity` has `GetUserId` and also `Name`, `AuthenticationType`, etc... But how do I get my `DisplayName` for display?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the claim in ClaimsIdentity:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("DisplayName", DisplayName));
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Created an extention method to read DisplayName from ClaimsIdentity:

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static string GetDisplayName(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
        }
        var ci = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (ci != null)
        {
            return ci.FindFirstValue("DisplayName");
        }
        return null;           
    }
}
```

In your view use it like:

```
User.Identity.GetDisplayName()
```

Comment: This seems promising... where do you normally place your `IdentiyExtensions` method? In the `IdentityModels.cs`? Or would you create a new file with certain name convention for it?

Comment: I would create a new file with name "IdentityExtensions.cs", probably inside a folder named "Helpers"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works! I make a little modification though... instead of returning `return claim.FindFirst("DisplayName")`, I return `return claim.FindFirst("DisplayName").ToString().Substring(("DisplayName: ").Length);` -- this is because `claim.FindFirst("DisplayName")` is of type `Claim` but the `return` needs to be a `string`. Also, if I do not put the `Substring`, it will display `DisplayName: myname` instead of just `myname`.

Comment: @Ian you are correct about returning string. I updated the the extension method.

Comment: I do not find the `FindFirstValue` method (there isn't one). Do I miss any reference? Thanks for the update - I accepted your answer anyway, since it already sufficiently points to the right answer. ;)

Comment: its in the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity namespace

Comment: I get it... forgot about `Ctrl + .` yep, thanks again!

Comment: Can I use this extension for  int values?