# Retrieving user info from db while having identity claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, claims-based-identity

I must admit, I'm newbie to MVC.. so everything is kind of like a black magic right now.

This is the code

```
        public ActionResult LogIn(Models.profile profile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(IsValid(profile.profile_email, profile.profile_password))
            {
                var db = new DatabaseContext();
                var _id = db.profile.Where(u => u.profile_email == profile.profile_email).Select(n => n.profile_id).FirstOrDefault();
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, profile.profile_email),
                                                          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, _id.ToString())}, 
                                                          "ApplicationCookie");
                var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
                var authmngr = ctx.Authentication;

                authmngr.SignIn(identity);

                return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Main");
            } else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something goes wrong");
            }
        }

        return View(profile);
    }
```

I've managed to login with the identity thing, which was quite hard @_ @
The thing was that those claimtype are not too flexible from what I've seen. 
I mean I have to choose something from the list and I kind just pick my own properties or something.

So, I decided to store current user ID in the `ClaimTypes.Name`. Not sure if it is any of the good idea. I'm not even sure if the whole login pattern is any viable ;o

But... to the point. How do I retrieve user infos with just this claim if there would be no user id in there? Or how could I retrieve users info from database at all with using claims identity?

If there is anything I should add, please let me know ;3

Comment: This may help: creating and using custom claim types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880269/how-to-do-session-management-in-aspnet-identity/32991423#32991423

Comment: @BrendanGreen Thanks, It happened to be usefull ;3