# Asp.net Identity MVC, How to get logged in users' name in _Layout. User.Identity.Name gives me email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

So my users should still login using their email adress, but I want my top menu to greet them by their Name. I have the name implemented and everything, I just need a way of getting it to show.

Currently I have this in my top menu.

```
Logged in as @User.Identity.Name
```

This gives me AppUser.EmailAddress, but i need the AppUser.Name

This is my Login action, currently it only contains data from the loginviewmodel (email, password, rememberme).

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel login, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(login);
            }

        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
            login.EmailAddress,
            login.Password,
            login.RememberMe, false);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            ViewBag.Succeeded = false;

            return View(login);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
```

The name exists in my AppUser class and my RegisterViewModel which is used by the register action.

I'm using Identity 3.0.0 but I welcome ways of solving it on other versions,

Comment: Load their name using the email address from the database and display that

Comment: Don't hit the database - ASP.NET Identity uses claims, and there is a specific claim type for a GivenName and Surname.  When the user logs on, set these claim values and use an extension method to display the value.  See my answer here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974228/can-you-extend-httpcontext-current-user-identity-properties/31976327#31976327

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out once I find the time.

Comment: Usermanager doesnt have the CreateIdentityAsync method anymore, nor can I find DefaultAuthenticationTypes in Identity 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Then you have `user` which you could use it like:

```
Var username=user.lastname;
```

Comment: Don't do this - you will uneccessarily hit the db on every request to get the user name. Since you're using Asp.net Identity, set the users name in a claim