# MVC User identity full name instead of username

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following

```
  @<div class="btn btn-info btn-user">@Html.ActionLink("hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "index", "Candidate", routeValues:=Nothing, htmlAttributes:=New With {.title = "Manage Your Profile"})</div>
```

Is there a way I can get the full name of the user instead of the username?

Comment: That depends on whether not the full name of the user is actually stored in the identity profile.

Comment: That's using ASP.NET Identity and claims.  I have an answer that might point you in the right direction here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974228/can-you-extend-httpcontext-current-user-identity-properties/31976327#31976327

Comment: I am using the otb mvc